# could not complete windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to install windows 7 ultimate from USB device. While installing, completing installation step not happening and system restarting and installation is starting from first. same thing happening again and again. What could be the problem? How can I get rid of this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you PC reboots remove the USB device. The installation must continue from the hard drive.